# Double polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a double polymorphic associations, basically i'm going to put in relation Questions model and VideoInterview model with Bond model. They are made in this way:

**bond migration**

```
class CreateBonds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bonds do |t|
      t.references :sourceable, :polymorphic => true
      t.references :targetable, :polymorphic => true
      t.string :operation
      t.string :score
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**bond.rb**

```
class Bond < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sourceable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :targetable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bonds, :as => :sourceable
  has_many :bonds, :as => :targetable
end
```

**video_interview.rb**

```
class VideoInterview < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bonds, :as => :sourceable
  has_many :bonds, :as => :targetable
end
```

How should i modify the model in orders to user this association correctly?
If I call @question.bonds, I think there is something wrong because sourceable and targetable are defined under the same has_many :bonds.
I'd like ti make @question.sources and get all the bonds with the question as sourceable element.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need have different names for your associations, naming both the associations bonds in case of sourceable and targetable will not work for you. you can name it any thing and provide a class_name to associate with bond model like this for the Question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sources, :class_name => 'Bond', :as => :sourceable
  has_many :targets, :class_name => 'Bond', :as => :targetable
end
```

and similarly for the VideoInterview Model

```
class VideoInterview < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sources, :class_name => 'Bond', :as => :sourceable
  has_many :targets, :class_name => 'Bond', :as => :targetable
end
```

now you can call functions like this @question.sources, @question.targets, @video_interview.sources, @video_interview.targets

hope that helps.

Comment: Does this really work for you?

I receive following error message

```ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (TreeLeaf(#70354416468820) expected, got #<TreeNode id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> which is an instance of TreeNode(#47140845690560))```

Where the class ```TreeLeaf``` corresponds to and holds the place of ```Bonds``` as value for ```:class_name```

:(